# Alsa Xrun Error and .asoundrc

Tags: c++, alsa

I have three USB sound card. my job is to develop a sound processing program. every things in my program are OK, but I have some troubles with Xrun error( overrun error). Really I have to not use Jack. So, I want to know if I define period size and buffer size for each sound card in .asoundrc. it can overcome with this problem?
if you think it can help me, so please let me know how this can be done in .asoundrc.

it is welcome if you have any suggestion for handling Xrun error in ALSA
thanks

Comment: Period/buffer sizes are set by your program. How do you synchronize the sample clocks of the three devices?